# Algorithm to construct a graph with minimal spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, trees, matroids

I need an algorithm that constructs an undirected graph given all of its minimal spanning trees (bases of a matroid) to find circles in the underlying graph. Has anyone an idea how I can do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "to find circles"? For example, deciding whether a given set of edges forms a circle in the graph is much simpler than reconstructing the whole graph. (Also, in most cases if a graph is not 3-connected then it is not uniquely determined by its spanning trees.)

Comment: You need to be more precise in specifying your input and output. Should the output be a simple graph(s)? Is the output a weighted graph(s)? Should output be just one instance, or all of them? If you want all of them, what if there's infinitely many possibilities?